# Reset GCP compute engine instance on stackdriver alert

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-stackdriver

I have stackdriver alerts setup that notify whenever the CPU utilisation for a compute engine instance falls below or rises above some thresholds.

I would like to restart the instance whenever this alert is fired.

How do I achieve this without having to write & maintain another vm or cloud function?

Does stackdriver or any other monitoring option on GCP let me reset instances based on an alert condition?

Answer (score 1):

I think that A **Stackdriver Alerting Policy won't be able to run any commands to stop or start a GCE VM by itself.**

Indeed you could use a Cloud Function with Cloud Scheduler for this or a cron on other GCE VM, as we can read here on this other *question* [1]. Cloud Scheduler gives you 3 free jobs per month [2] and Cloud Functions has the following pricing [3].

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817919/automatic-script-to-turn-off-and-on

[2] https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/pricing

[3] https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing